# How to use active in NavLink using MUI Mean from MenuItem and using themed components with mui 5.15.14 version

Tags: material-ui, mui-x

This is button for menu options

```
   <Button 
            id="nav-button-menu"
          
            aria-controls={open ? 'nav-menu' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
           
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            Home
        </Button>
```

below are the menu for links

```
   <Menu
            id="nav-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            MenuListProps={{
                'aria-labelledby': 'nav-button-menu',
            }}
        >
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} component={NavLink} to="/run" >RUN</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} component={NavLink} to="/test">TEST</MenuItem>
      
        </Menu>
```

When user click on meanitem  of RUN or Test then based isactive state of user clicked mean item ,how we can set boxShadow based on isactive of  meanitem.